# Windows Explorer opens instead of start menu shortcuts (like Control Panel)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, control-panel

Every time I click on *My Computer » Control Panel » Default Programs*, it opens a Windows Explorer document page.

I cannot restore my PC for the same reason. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start System Restore by typing `%systemroot%\system32\rstrui.exe` into the Run dialog (Start menu -> Run, or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).